# Error plotting an ellipse in R

Tags: r, vector, ellipse, mu, sigmaplot

I am trying to plot an ellipse in R but getting an error message. Here is my code:

```
library(mixtools)       ###I also tried library(ellipse)
mu<-c(.564,.603)
sigma<-matrix(c(0.0144,0.0117,0.0117,0.0146),2)
ellipse(mu,sigma,alpha=0.95,npoints=200,newplot=TRUE,type="l")
```

Result:

```
Error in ellipse(mu, sigma, alpha = 0.05, npoints = 200, newplot = TRUE,  : 
unused arguments (alpha = 0.05, npoints = 200, newplot = TRUE, type = "l")
```

Then I tried just this:

```
ellipse(mu, sigma)
```

Result:

```
Error in ellipse(mu, sigma) : argument "vec" is missing, with no default
```

I am not sure argument "vec" is missing unless i do not know what that means.

I then turned my "mu" into a matrix may be that will help but got same result.

```
mu<-matrix(c(.564,.603),ncol=1)
sigma<-matrix(c(0.0144,0.0117,0.0117,0.0146),2)
ellipse(mu,sigma,alpha=0.05,npoints=200,newplot=TRUE,type="l")
```

I uninstalled R and re-istalled the latest but to no avail.

I checked: `??ellipse`

I seem to be writing the code correctly but with no success.

Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Try using `mixtools::ellipse(...)` instead of `ellipse(...)`. Your code works for me but somehow the error message you get suggests that you have another `ellipse` function defined earlier in the search path.

Comment: @flodel: Thanks very much, mixtools::ellipse(...) did work. I have been trying this for almost 4 weeks, I stopped trying after a while.